# Load multiple components using routing in an angular library

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, shared-libraries, router, angular-library

I am trying to create module in library which will have different components and which can be based on routes, But issue faced while testing the library is , its not able to find and route to the component i am trying to refer.

Also if i change the path to '' in any of the below component and routes defined in app Test , then it will work for that component, but with paths defined issue is coming
1) Test Module File in library

```
   const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'view', component: ViewComponent },
      { path: 'apply', component: ApplyComponent },
    ];

    @NgModule({
    declarations: [ViewComponent,ApplyComponent],
    imports: [
       ReactiveFormsModule,
       CommonModule,
       RouterModule.forChild(routes)
     ],exports:[
        ViewComponent,ApplyComponent
     ]
    })
    export class TestModule { }
```

2)Routing file in test app which imports library from the module

```
   const routes: Routes = [
     {
       path: 'applyTest',
       children: [
         { path: 'apply', loadChildren: './app-test.module#AppTestModule' }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'viewTest',
        children: [
          { path: 'view', loadChildren: './app-test.module#AppTestModule' }
         ]
       }
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is being imported in app.module.ts
3) AppTestModule in test app

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import {TestModule } from 'testLib';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        TestModule 
      ]
    })
    export class AppTestModule{ }
```

4) SideNavigationhtml in test app

```
    <a  [routerLink]="['/applyTest' ]">Apply Test</a>       
    <a  [routerLink]="['/viewTest' ]">View Test</a>
```

When I try to click on router link, nothing is getting loaded, I am expecting either ViewComponent/ApplyComponent to be loaded based on the click

Comment: Where are you importing  lazy module routes in your app ( second point )?

Comment: Have you imported the AppRoutingModule in your AppTestModule imports array?

Comment: No, its imported in app.module.ts

imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
  ... 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: I am lazy loading the TestModule  of my library in AppTestModule,

Comment: Ok, so you need to import 'AppTestModule' in your 'AppModule ' imports array